# Angles to decimal conversion

Tags: language-agnostic, math, geometry

I'm trying to understand some flash animation, and am having difficulty working out the following.  Can anyone help?

I want to convert a degree range of 0 to 90, to a value between 0 and 1

These is an existing function to convert from the range 0 to 1 to degrees,  eg:

```
function convertToDegrees(Int:Pos)
{
    var rot = (45 * pos);  
    var degrees = (90 - ( rot * 2 ));  

    return degrees;
}
```

Now to convert backwards, from degrees to 0 to 1 value, I am trying: 
(WHICH IS WRONG)

```
function convertFromDegrees(Int:currentDegreeValue )
{
    var rot =  (currentDegreeValue / 2) + 90;  
    var Pos = rot / 45;

    return Pos;  
}
```

Can anyone help me as to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first function could be simplified to `90 * (1 - pos)`, so the reverse function would be `1 - (degrees / 90)`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to convert a degree range of 0 to 90, to a value between 0 and 1

How about:

```
x / 90.0
```

Comment: Since he accepted the other answer, frank must've meant that he wanted "to convert a degree range of **90 to 0**, to a value between **0 and 1** "

Answer (score 0):

rot = (90 - degrees) / 2